# convert spaces between columns to tab

Tags: text-processing

I have a file with thousands of rows and I need to convert all the spaces between columns to tabs. This file is read inside a python script which will fail if the columns are not tab separated.

Comment: Since you are asking this, I am assuming you cannot/don't know how to change the python script to accept spaces, so I removed the python tag.

Comment: let me give you more details as per my script it will read 3rd coloumn and the coloums will be tab spaced. it will throw an error if the file is not tab spaced

Comment: Yes, but if you wrote the script, you can easily change it. I am guessing you did not write the script and cannot change it, and therefore need to change the input file instead, right?

Comment: it is like i receive a file from different source mostly it is tab spaced  and sometimes it is not . i pick the third column add some prefix and suffix and do some database update . so i want to add one command which corrects the coloumn and make sure it is tab space

Comment: Yes, but do you want to do this in the python script or before passing the file to the python script? Is my answer enough or not?

Comment: I want to do inside my python script. I still i am not sure how to do inside the script.

Comment: with open('a_file_1', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        fields = line.split('\t')
        SDN = fields[2]
        with open("b_file.csv", "a") as F:
            F.write(SDN)
            F.write('\n')
for a in glob.glob("b_file.csv"):
    df=pd.read_csv(a)
    df1 = "'13" + df["SDN"].map(str) + "'"

Comment: Then please [edit] your question and include the script. We can't help you modify a script you don't show us. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting for help on how to format your code as code.

Comment: It would help to see a bit of the input data and expected result.

Comment: this is the input file
17/09/2020 770 870456 u_NUMBER 18/06/2020 7045
17/09/2020 770 870289 u_NUMBER 18/06/2020 7028
17/09/2020 770 870401 u_NUMBER 18/06/2020 7040

script should read third coloumn

required o/p
SDN
13870456
13870289
13870401

Comment: That's useless to us. Please [edit] your question and paste it there. With formatting using the `{}` button

Answer (score 3):

To replace all occurrences of two or more spaces to tabs in a file, with GNU `sed` or compatible, use:

```
sed 's/   */\t/g' file > newfile
```

To change all spaces, even single ones (this assumes that you can never have a space within a field), use this:

```
sed 's/ /\t/g' file > newfile
```

And, to edit the file in place and avoid creating a new file, you can use `-i`:

```
sed -i 's/   */\t/g' file
```

Comment: `sed -i 's/  */\t/g' file ` (system did not allowed to edit 3chars only)

Comment: D'oh! Thanks, @schweik.

Answer (score 0):

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl6)**

```
~$ raku -pe 's:g/ \s+ /\t/;' file.txt > newfile.txt
```

HTH.

https://raku.org/